# Should the uegt tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [Top Ubuntu Download manger with bandwidth limiter and](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198472/top-ubuntu-download-manger-with-bandwidth-limiter-and) is tagged with [uegt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uegt).

From the context I'd say the OP should have used the tag [uget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uget) instead.
The mentioned question is the only question using the tag [uegt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uegt).  The tag has no wiki and does not seem to make any sense.

Shouldn't the tag [uegt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uegt) be removed?

Comment: Related on [meta.se]: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/468333)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report, I believe you are correct and just edited the question and replaced the tag with [uget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uget) as you suggested. The system will automatically remove the tag soon when it is not in use any more.

Next time, if it seems to be just a typo or any other case where you can be quite sure, you may also just edit the question yourself directly. Worst case if the OP or anyone reviewing it disagrees, it can be rolled back.

Comment: Excerpt from [related faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/468333): *Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day*

Comment: I saw that question and wondered if it was a typo, but *errd* on the side of caution and left it... There are risks to editing detail as none of us have the capacity to know everything..